# String to long double conversion in c++98

Tags: c++, c++98

Anyone know how to convert a `string` to `long double`? For example lets say we have

```
string S = "3.236568949"
```

I want to take what inside the string and convert it to a long double variable `x`.

Note: In c++11 their exist `stold` function do so but I'm using c++98 not c++11. 
 Also I don't need to cout the string with certain precision because I know `setprecision` function already  but what I want is just to convert to `long double`. In other wards,I need x to equal the **exact** number inside the string and not an approximated version of the number. Finally I want to tell you that my string contains a valid number.

Comment: "exact number inside the string"... good luck with that.

Comment: there's no way to get the exact value unless you're using a decimal floating-point type

Answer (score 0):

you can use the C function :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
   char* convertme="3.236568949";
   double converted=atof(convertme);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP wants `long double`, `atof()` returns `double`

Comment: The OP wants a `long double`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::stringstream` to convert the string into a `long double`.  The `std::stringstream` acts just like `cin` but instead of getting the input from the user you load it into the stream with a `std::string`.  That looks like

```
std::string data = "3.236568949"
std::stringstream ss(data);
long double ld;
ss >> ld;
```

---

Do note that when dealing with floating point numbers you are going to have to deal with imprecision.  For more on this see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: your code wokrs very well , can i select certain percision for ld ?

Comment: @user288086 You cannot set the precision of the output but you can specify precision for things you input into the `stringstream`.

Comment: @user288086 Just like you would using `cout`.

Comment: tell me how please.

Comment: @user288086 Well, you could extract a substring from the original string with only the desired figures or do something like [this](https://ideone.com/9w8srR), but given the nature of floating point representation (please, read the Q&A linked by NathanOliver and the mentioned [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)) it seems quite an exercise in futility.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`strtold()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) function from C99:

```
long double d = strtold( str.c_str(), nullptr );
```

to convert `std::string` to `long double`. Though floating point representation is approximate so nobody would guarantee that value after conversion is exactly the same is in your string.

Comment: This function is only available in C++ in C++11.  The OP needs a C++98 solution.

Comment: This function is avaiilable in C99

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually I think it's C.

Comment: Being in C99 does not mean it is part of C++98

Comment: It does not mean that C99 is unavailable either

Comment: The OP clearly wants a C++98 answer.  I fail to see why giving them a C99 answer helps them.

Comment: C++98 is orthogonal to C99 and the fact that this solution requires C99 I mentioned in my answer. OP may use old compiler which only supports C98 or required by company policy or whatever not to enable C++11.